# Facebook api Get users who invite members to group

Tags: facebook-graph-api, members, facebook-group

I want to get id, name of users who invite their friends to Facebook group. I tried this api to get users who requested to join groups

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/group_id/member_requests?access_token=[token]
```

but it only shows the list of requested users without inviters info

Anyone have any solution?

Comment: I don’t think that info is available via API at all.

Comment: Do you have any idea to have that info?

Comment: i am with CBroe here, i am pretty sure there is no API. in other words: it´s not possible.